# How do I enable --debug for node.js when running GeddyJS

Tags: node.js

GeddyJS is started by running `geddy` from the root of the project.

I'm having some trouble getting [GeddyJS](http://geddyjs.org/) to run under node.js with debug enabled.

getty installs /usr/local/bin/geddy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
...
```

which I made a quick copy of, and amended the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --debug
...
```

but that does not work, because env can't find 'node --debug'.

I then tried to write a wrapper script to act as the interpreter in the shebang line here:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/env node --debug $@
```

And this time, node is started with a debugger enabled, but the paths must be messed up, or environment must be different, because I am getting missing module exceptions:

```
$ geddy-debug
debugger listening on port 5858

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/geddy'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object. (/usr/local/bin/geddy-debug:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
```

This of course works fine if I don't try to enable debugging.

I want to debug in eclipse as per : https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger, which works great with just `node --debug scriptname.js`

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It looks like Geddy has a `--debug` option. Does that only debug Geddy, not Node?

Comment: It seems to set the log verbosity level, but does not enable node's --debug option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, so others can benefit if they happen to see this:

From the project directory, override the shebang line and invoke the interpreter directly to run the geddy script:

`/usr/bin/env node --debug /usr/local/bin/geddy`

Comment: How did this turn out for you? I'm trying to debug a geddy app as well when I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587655/no-breakpoints-are-hit-with-geddy

I'm not able to set/hit any breakpoints. Were you?

Comment: I ended up ditching geddy. I found a better path through express.js to build my app at the time.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I'm using express now and I'm looking to move on to flatiron possibly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Debugging Geddy WikiPage](https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Debugging) with a bit more info.